# How can a remote ssh tunnel port be closed on the ssh server when the ssh command goes away?

Tags: ssh, sshd

I'm creating a tunnel from a client to a server like:

```
ssh -N \
  -o ConnectTimeout=9 \
  -o ServerAliveInterval=5 \
  -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 \
  -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes \
  -R 0.0.0.0:10021:localhost:22  \
  foo@example.com
```

If I unplug the client ethernet it times out:

```
Timeout, server example.com not responding.
```

If I immediately try to reconnect, it says:

```
Error: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 10021
```

This is because the server still shows:

```
sudo netstat -tnlpa | grep 10021
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10021           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30173/sshd: foo
```

How can I have the server's `sshd` close the port as soon as the client connection disappears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server doesn't know that the client connection disappeared!

The client knows this because you have ServerAliveCountMax, so it correctly exits when it's no longer receiving messages from the server. But it has no way of *informing the server* that it has exited (because your ethernet is still unplugged, so even TCP RSTs cannot get through).

The server will *eventually* notice the client's absence due to TCPKeepAlive being active, but this will take somewhat longer until it kicks in – possibly a few minutes.

To make this work with the rapid timeout that you want, you'll need a similar setting **on the server**. Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to include (for example) these settings:

```
ClientAliveInterval 5
ClientAliveCountMax 1
```

These settings can be inside a `Match` block if you want to make them per-user.

Comment: Mentioning the `Match` feature is crucial for my application as well.  Thanks!